# Hide class members from everything except another specific assembly

Tags: c#, dll, mono, unity-container, monodevelop

I have two class libraries "MyLibrary.dll" and "MyLibraryEditor.dll" for a Unity runtime and editor extension. There are several class members inside "MyLibrary.dll" that are only intended for use by "MyLibraryEditor.dll".

My first thought was to use the `internal` keyword because I mistakenly thought that this constrained visibility to a namespace. Instead it is clear that this keyword limits visibility to the assembly.

What is the best way to constrain access to some class members to "MyLibrary.dll" and "MyLibraryEditor.dll" without hurting performance? Also, reflection is not an option.

I am happy to simply not document the functions, but unfortunately Intellisense (and MonoDevelop's equivalent) show these members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want internals in one assembly to be visible from another assembly, you can use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute on the assembly containing the internals.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyLibraryEditor")]
```

That answered, you might want to rethink your architectural design so that you don't need to use it, since it will open up all internals to the other assembly, not only the ones that you want.

Comment: Beat me by 10 seconds on this, so I deleted and gave it to you.

Comment: Unfortunately I am constrained because I need some of these properties to be accessible by Unity `MonoBehaviour` serialization (which cannot be done manually). If this was a non-Unity library then I would be implementing this in an entirely different way.

Comment: The only other option would be to use an explicitly implemented interface to hide this... I will try `InternalsVisibleTo` and see how that works with Mono :-) cheers!

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! It doesn't show up in MonoDevelop Intellisense at all now, and compilation behaviour is as expected :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could make the members `internal` but use [`[InternalsVisibleTo]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to give access to those members to the other assembly. They'd still be visible within the *same* assembly as well, of course... there's no way of getting round that.

I primarily use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` for giving access to internal members to test classes, and would *try* to avoid doing this for non-test purposes - but sometimes it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using pure C# concepts. You are two seperate assemblies, that is as far seperate as you can get, and there is no relationship between the two as far as .Net is concerned.

you could do some things with signing or validation to make it so it would be difficult to use one assembly without the other, but not something you can do to prevent visibility of the classes/members.

Comment: How do you square this with `InternalsVisibleTo`?

Comment: I was not aware of that attribute is how!